# Dependency Errors While Running Yarn On Ubuntu For Local Installation of Polkadot-JS/apps

Tags: polkadot-js, error

I am attempting to compile and run polkadot-JS/apps on Ubuntu cloud server (Digital Ocean). I have Node.JS and yarn installed. While running "yarn" in the polkadot-JS/apps folder, I get a number of dependency errors. I was careful not to use npm. Most of the errors reference webpack and react. I tried "yarn add webpack" and "yarn add react" but I get the same out put every time. Screenshot attached. Any ideas how to fix this? Would it be possible instead to compile it outside of the ubuntu VPS environment (like on an ubuntu laptop) and then just upload the compiled code?

[image: Screenshot with yarn dependency errors]

Comment: Did you follow this steps: https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps#development ?

Comment: Yes. Those were the exact instructions I was following. Those caused a problem on Ubuntu in that you have to install yarn in just the right ways using this command: curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
(Don’t use the ususal yarn install command or ubuntu will install cmdtest instead and you will have to remove it using “sudo apt remove cmdtest” and start the installation of yarn again) But otherwise, I was following the directions at that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED - it turns out that the dependency errors do not actually affect the running or performance of the UI. Ignore them and proceed.